# Do all tables have non trivial functional dependencies?

Tags: database-design

I am asking this question because if a table has a key that consists of all of is attributes then the table would have a trivial functional dependency since the right side is a subset of the left side. 
For example I have relation R with attributes A and B. A and B together are the key of the relation R. Thus I have FD A B -> A B which is a trivial dependency and thus this table only has trivial functional dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you pretty much answered your own question, let me try to restate it in a (hopefully) clearer way...

- All attributes are functionally dependent on the key.
- If the key "covers" all attributes, then all these dependencies are trivial (by definition).
- OTOH, if there are attributes outside the key (even within *another* key), then they are non-trivially dependent on the key (again, by definition).